# Converting many table into one table mysql databae

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with hundreds of tables. I want to convert this into a single table, where the table name will be added to the records, meaning that for each row / data in a particular table, I will add a new field, where in this new field the value will be the table name. Is there any way to do this automatically, rather than I have to create a new field on every table and insert the table name manually, this will take year. The record that I have on this db is around 400000 records. Can mysqldump with a script do this? or any other way ?

Comment: Write a python/ruby to script, it should be fairly easy.

Comment: Are all the column definitions (name, datatype, length, default etc.) the same on every table? What about triggers, views, constraints, primary/unique keys etc? Also, how will you handle the auto_increment columns if any?

Comment: yes all the column definitions are the same on every table. There is no triggers, view or constraints and primary / unique keys. There is no auto_increment columns.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to generate syntax of the form:

```
create table xxx as
    select t.*, 'table1' as TableName from table1 t union all
    select t.*, 'table2' as TableName from table2 t union all
    . . .
```

You can create the select statements using:

```
select concat('select t.*, ''', Table_Name, ''' as TableName from ', Table_Name, ' union all '
from Information_Schema.Tables
```

You can then put the `create table` line in front and remove the final `union all`.